# Есть страница html, ее нужно свзять с php, все это дело лежит в cms, но они должны существовать обособленно, как это сделать?

Tags: php, html

Нужен какой-то один роутер-php, но чтобы он не влиял на работу cms, а только выводил данные в html. Есть идеи?

Comment: В html который создает cms?

Comment: @Erm, вот как раз нет. В этом вся и проблема.

Comment: какая cms есмь?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin самописная, не мной. ( Думаю, остается только подключать phtml, но проблема ужасного урла...

Comment: Вы не пробовали в обход точки входа системы, по абсолютной ссылке вызвать кастонмый файл? Единственное, что ссылка не должна содержать алиасы из роута системы. Обычно такое срабатывает

Comment: @KirillKorushkin http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu.php - а как от расширения избавиться?

Comment: через .htaccess  https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/remove-file-extensions

Comment: @KirillKorushkin у меня nginx, спасибо. )

Comment: https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess

Comment: @KirillKorushkin предалагает сохранить страницу...(

Comment: @KirillKorushkin работает)) Спасибки) Я обращалась к test.php

Comment: завсегда пжлста)